A-lattices for Dedekind domains
So, in classical number theory if $A$ is a Dedekind domain coming from a global field, like $A = \mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{F}_q[t]$, we can define $A$-lattices in a $k_v$-vector space $V$ as finitely generated $A$-submodules that spans $V$ over $k_v$. Here, $k$ is the fraction field of $A$ and $v$ is a discrete valuation and $k_v$ denotes the completion of $k$ w.r.t. $v$. Such a lattice satisfies a lot of properties, like torsion-free, discrete and cocompact in $V$. I'm wondering for any general Dedekind domain $A$, especially the case that $k_v$ is not a local field, do we have a similar result? I believe yes but I did not find any reference. Wondering if you know there're any textbooks or papers talking about this. I guess I need to cite results like this in my paper if there're.
To make this more precise, we start with a field $k$ and a smooth geometrically irreducible projective curve $X$ over $k$. We fixed a closed point $\infty\in X$. Then, $X = \operatorname{Spec} A\cup \{\infty\}$ for some $k$-algebra $A$, which is a Dedekind domain. Let $K = \operatorname{Frac}(A)$ and $K_\infty$ the completion w.r.t. $v_\infty$. Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $K_\infty$, say $\dim_{K_\infty}V = n$. We can define an $A$-lattice $M$ in $V$ as a discrete sub-$A$-module in $V$ that spans $V$ over $K_\infty$, i.e. $K_\infty\cdot M = V$. Then, one should be able to find a $K_\infty$-basis $\{e_1,\cdots,e_n\}\subseteq M$. Now, we can consider $N = \sum_{i=1}^nAe_i\subseteq M\subseteq V$. So, $M/N\subseteq V/N$. It remains to prove that $M/N$ is a torsion $A$-module.
Assume that we know $M/N$ is torsion. But $M$ has finite $A$-rank and torsion-free, then $M$ is finitely generated. So, we know that $M/N$ is finitely generated, then by the classification theorem of finitely generated torsion modules over a Dedekind domain, $M/N\cong A/\mathfrak{p}_1^{m_1}\oplus \cdots A/\mathfrak{p}_l^{m_l}$ for some maximal ideals $\mathfrak{p}_i$. Each of them is a finite dimensional vector space over $k$. Thus, $M/N$ is finite dimensional over $k$.
So, how do we prove $M/N$ is torsion. Also is the converse true? i.e. if $M/N$ is finite dimensional over $k$, is $M$ discrete in $V$?

I figure out the proof of the converse. It remains to prove $M/N$ is torsion now.
